# Transaction broadcast mechanism

Tags: go-ethereum, transaction-propagation

After initiation of transaction, transaction will remain in the transaction pool of all peered nodes.

1. How Transaction reach to the transaction pool after receiving by the node?
2. Do transaction broadcast to all known peer before reaching to its local transaction pool of node?